# Store Jtextfield input in Arraylist then print contents of Arraylist

Tags: java, swing

This is my first time creating a GUI. I can create text fields just fine, but am having trouble collecting user input and storing their input into an Arraylist.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

textField1 = new JTextField("Enter resident name",20); 
  add(textField1); 

  textField2 = new JTextField("How many accounts to enter data for?",20);
  add(textField2); 

  textField3 = new JTextField("Enter account #",20);
  add(textField4); 

  textField3 = new JTextField("Enter data for account",20);
  add(textField5);
```

1. If the user enters "4" into textField2, I would like "Enter account #" and "Enter data for account" to then appear four times (resulting in 8 new textfields)
2. I would like the user to be able to click a "Store" button that places textfields 1-5 (and more if they want to enter a lot of accounts) into an arraylist that can later be retrieved and print **all** stored array info (show all resident and all accounts info), similar to something like below:

   ```
   ArrayList accounts = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

   Account exampleAccount = new Account();
   exampleAccount.setFirstName("John");
   exampleAccount.setLastName("Doe");
   exampleAccount.setBalance(101.13d);

   accounts.add(exampleAccount);

   for(Account account : accounts) {
       System.out.println("Name: " + account.getFirstName() + " " + account.getLastName() + 
               ".  Balance: " + account.getBalance());
   // Or override Account's toString() method and do System.out.println(account.toString()) 
   }
3. Would like the form "reset" so that after each time the user clicks "Store" they can enter a new resident's information.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You could use a DocumentListener or InputVerifier depending on your needs

Comment: I wild focus on how you would get the user to input the values for one account and how you would go about getting the values from it, from there, doing it n number of times becomes easier

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this..

```
    textField1 = new JTextField("Enter resident name", 20);
    add(textField1);

    textField2 = new JTextField("How many accounts to enter data for?", 20);
    add(textField2);

    textField2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int count = Integer.valueOf(textField2.getText());

            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                textField3 = new JTextField("Enter account #", 20);
                add(textField4);

                textField3 = new JTextField("Enter data for account", 20);
                add(textField5);
            }

        }
    });
```